# Finding a point on a plane closest to another point

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the point $(1,1,1)$ and the plane $2x+2y+z = 0$. I want to find a point that is closest to my point on the plane.

In other words, I want to find a point along the line $(1,1,1)+t(2,2,1)$ but on my plane. Notice that the vector $(2,2,1)$ is my normal vector and therefore I want to find the point parallel to this vector, but from my original point.

I need a nudge to complete this problem! Thank you.

Comment: If a point on the line $(1,1,1) + t(2,2,1)$ is in the plane what equations must hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: A general point on the line has the form $(x,y,z) = (1 + 2t, 1 + 2t, 1 + t)$, and for this to be on the plane, it must satisfy the equation of the plane. Plug those in and solve for $t$.

Comment: $1+2t,1+2t,1+t = 2x+2y+z$ gives me the point (0.5,0.5,0) if I want $t$ to equal x, y and z...I must be doing this wrong?

Comment: @user3200098: You want $x=1+2t$, $y=1+2t$, $z=1+t$. As well as $2x+2y+z=0$. That's 4 linear equations and 4 unknowns.

Comment: @user3200098: Why do you want $t$ to equal $x,y,$ and $z$? You have $$x=1+2t,$$ $$y=1+2t,$$ and $$z=1+t,$$ since $(x,y,z)$ is on your line. You also have $$2x+2y+z=0,$$ since $(x,y,z)$ is on your plane. Rewrite that last equation using the first three, then figure out what $t$ has to be, which will tell you what $x,y,$ and $z$ are.

Comment: Okay so $t=\frac{-5}{9}$? How does this give me my distance now?

Edit: Ok give me a minute

Comment: The distance is 5/3!

Comment: I've got the plane $x-2y+2z = 6$ and the point $1,7,-4$ using the same methods I get the closest point to be $2.9,2.9,0.2$ but I'm pretty sure it's incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The distance between point $\;(a,b,c)\in\Bbb R^3\;$ and the plane $\;Ax+By+Cz+D=0\;$ is given by

$$\frac{|Aa+Bb+Cc+D|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}}$$

After you do the above (Result: $\;\sqrt3\;$), now just substitute in the euclidean distance formula with a general point  on the plane .